# George became a writer of detective stories. (What / Which) did George become a writer of?

Tags: pronouns, interrogatives, wh-questions

In the declarative sentence：

> George became a writer of detective stories.

We changed it to interrogative sentence：

> **(What / Which)** did George become a writer of?

Should I use **What** or **Which**?

Answer (score 4):

You only use "which" when you present a choice of answers. For example, if you presented someone with an apple, a banana, and an orange, you might ask "which would you like?"

As yours is an open question, you should use "what".

A more formal construction of the question would be:

> Of what did George become a writer?

Comment: I have never seen **of what** before. I have been alway thinking only **of which** is right.

Comment: @Y.zeng Only if it were presented as a multiple choice question could you use "which".... for example "(a) Crime, (b) Fantasy, (c) Romance - of which was George a writer?"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learnt a new knowledge.